# Access Dropbox API from a Server located in Mainland China?

Tags: dropbox-api, dropbox-php, great-firewall-of-china

does anybody know, if the Dropbox API can be accessed from a server located in mainland China? All my tests from within China fail - same Application inside Europe works well.

If Dropbox access is really blocked in China - is there any other "Cloud" you could recommend, that can be accessed with an API via PHP?

Thank You!

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206992986-Dropbox-API-Access-from-Server-within-mainland-china ]

Comment: Does anybody have experience with the AlibabaCloud?
https://intl.aliyun.com/product